# Java String parameter needed - object given

Tags: java, keycloak

I am learning Java and I hope someone can help me here with the following problem.

Some information first:

- Keycloak update v16.1.0 to v19.0.1
- quarkus should not be used at the moment
- interface "EmailSenderProvider" was implemented and worked with v16.1.0
- EmailSenderProvider in v19.0.1 has two methods

  - public void send (default) -> parameters: UserModel user, 3x Strings
  - public void send -> parameters: 4x Strings

The problem now:
v16.1.0 had only one method (UserModel user, 3x Strings). That is not working anymore, because I have to implement the method with 4x Strings. I should not import a method with an empty body.

Code example:

```
  @Override
  public void send(final Map<String, String> config, final UserModel user, final String subject, final String textBody, final String htmlBody)
      throws EmailException {

    try {
      final String address = retrieveEmailAddress(user);
```

Method "retrieveEmailAddress" take just an object and save the emailaddress into a String:

```
  protected String retrieveEmailAddress(final UserModel user) {
    return user.getEmail();
  }
```

I have no more ideas how to get the emailaddress out of an object into a String parameter...

Thanks in advance.

Have a good day

Comment: what's the error that is thrown? what exactly does not work? what does `UserModel.getEmail()` return?

Comment: no error. I just need to change the send message. Now I am using the parameter "final UserModel user" -> after update to v19 this method is default and I need to implement the same method where "UserModel user" was changed to "String address".

I need a possibility to get the email address out of an object into this "String address" parameter...

Comment: the [keycloak docs](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/19.0.1/javadocs/org/keycloak/models/UserModel.html) on UserModel is in line with your code. what is the actual return value here `final String address = retrieveEmailAddress(user);`?

Comment: thanks for your help so far.
the actual return is the email address from users out of the database. in fact there is no error if I implement both methods (the default one with UserModel user parameter - which is used, and the second send method which is not used. the second method is only implemented with an empty body. if I delete this method an error occurs that I have to implement all methods from the interface. so I should refactor the code to use only the second method which have to be implemented. the first method is optional (default). but the second method uses only Strings as params.

Comment: maybe do it the way it's done in the default implementation? see the `DefaultEmailProvider` class code on [github](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/main/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/email/DefaultEmailSenderProvider.java)

Comment: thanks for helping tom - I think this should work. thank you.